# Swing: JFrame appears black after new container is added

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, server

new user looking for help with a college assignment.

The assignment is to create a multithreaded chat client that can compress and encrypt messages, send them to a server then have the relevant message sent to others. I've begun testing the code but I've run into a wall. See, when the GUI first opens, it opens as a login screen, which is sent off to the server to be validated. What is supposed to happen next is the login screen should close and a chat GUI open for the users within the same JFrame. But the problem I'm getting is that the login screen freezes in place and the rest of the window goes black, like so:
[JFrame error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfuI8.png)

The window then becomes completely unresponsive and I have to terminate the threads via Eclipse's console. This problem is preventing me from testing the rest of my code. Any help appreciated. The code for the Client class is below. If more code is needed, let me know. Thanks for any help you can offer!

I also apologise if the code alignment isn't great. I'm still learning!

```
public class YourChat_Client extends JFrame {
//GUI Components
private JTextField chatField;
private JTextPane broadcastPane;
private Container c; 
private JButton logonButton, btnArken, btnBen, btnDarklark, btnFree, btnSend,btnQuit, btnGroup;
private JPanel logonFieldsPanel, logonButtonPanel;
private JLabel usernameLabel, passwordLabel, chatLbl;
private JTextArea outputArea, playerArea, broadcastArea;
private JTextField username;
private JPasswordField password;
private JTextField broadcastField;
private Boolean loggedOn;
private int participantNo;
//Declare Socket
Socket socket;
YourChat_ClientThread thread;

//Data Streams
ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream;
ObjectInputStream clientInputStream;
public YourChat_Client() {
    super("YourChat_Client");
    setResizable(false);
    addWindowListener
    (   new WindowAdapter()
    {   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {   System.exit(0);
    }
    }
            );
    setTitle("Login");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(594,243);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // create and add GUI components for login screen (Taken from practical 7)
    c = getContentPane(); 
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  

    // GUI components for the username
    logonFieldsPanel = new JPanel(); 
    logonFieldsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,5,5));
    usernameLabel = new JLabel("Enter Username: ");
    logonFieldsPanel.add(usernameLabel);
    username = new JTextField(10);
    logonFieldsPanel.add(username);

    // GUI components for the password
    passwordLabel = new JLabel("Enter Password: ");
    logonFieldsPanel.add(passwordLabel);
    password = new JPasswordField(10);
    logonFieldsPanel.add(password);
    c.add(logonFieldsPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // panel for the logon button
    logonButtonPanel = new JPanel();
    logonButton = new JButton("logon");
    logonButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            attemptLogin();
        }   
    });
    logonButtonPanel.add(logonButton);
    c.add(logonButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
}
void sendMessage(String message){
    try {
        String output = "m" + message;
        CompressedMessage mess = new CompressedMessage(output);
        clientOutputStream.writeInt(participantNo);
        clientOutputStream.writeObject(mess);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
void setUpChat(Boolean loggedOn){

    c.remove(logonButtonPanel);
    c.remove(logonFieldsPanel);

    if(loggedOn){

        setResizable(true);
        setSize(543,243);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        c.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        chatLbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("chat.png"));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_chatLbl = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_chatLbl.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_chatLbl.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_chatLbl.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_chatLbl.gridx = 1;
        gbc_chatLbl.gridy = 1;
        c.add(chatLbl, gbc_chatLbl);

        broadcastPane = new JTextPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_broadcastPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_broadcastPane.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_broadcastPane.gridheight = 4;
        gbc_broadcastPane.gridwidth = 6;
        gbc_broadcastPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_broadcastPane.gridx = 5;
        gbc_broadcastPane.gridy = 2;
        c.add(broadcastPane, gbc_broadcastPane);

        btnArken = new JButton("Arken");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnArken = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnArken.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnArken.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnArken.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnArken.gridy = 4;
        c.add(btnArken, gbc_btnArken);

        btnBen = new JButton("Ben");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnBen = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnBen.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnBen.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnBen.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnBen.gridy = 5;
        c.add(btnBen, gbc_btnBen);

        btnDarklark = new JButton("Darklark");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnDarklark = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnDarklark.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnDarklark.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnDarklark.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnDarklark.gridy = 6;
        c.add(btnDarklark, gbc_btnDarklark);

        btnFree = new JButton("Free");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnFree = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnFree.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnFree.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnFree.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnFree.gridy = 7;
        c.add(btnFree, gbc_btnFree);

        chatField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_chatField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_chatField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_chatField.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_chatField.gridwidth = 6;
        gbc_chatField.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_chatField.gridx = 5;
        gbc_chatField.gridy = 7;
        c.add(chatField, gbc_chatField);
        chatField.setColumns(10);

        btnGroup = new JButton("Group");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnGroup = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnGroup.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnGroup.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnGroup.gridx = 2;
        gbc_btnGroup.gridy = 8;
        c.add(btnGroup, gbc_btnGroup);

        btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnQuit = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnQuit.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnQuit.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_btnQuit.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnQuit.gridx = 5;
        gbc_btnQuit.gridy = 9;
        c.add(btnQuit, gbc_btnQuit);

        btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnSend = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnSend.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_btnSend.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc_btnSend.gridheight = 2;
        gbc_btnSend.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_btnSend.gridx = 8;
        gbc_btnSend.gridy = 9;
        c.add(btnSend, gbc_btnSend);

        c.revalidate();
        c.repaint();


    } else{

        //if login fails, display an error message, close the data flow streams, and dispose of the window
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logon unsuccessful. \nConnection Terminated.", "Login Unsuccessful", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        setEnabled(false);
        closeStreams();
        dispose();
    }
}

void attemptLogin(){
    try {
        //get username from text area and encrypt
        String loginName = username.getText();
        EncryptedMessage uname = new EncryptedMessage(loginName);
        //get password from text area and encrypt
        String loginPword = new String(password.getPassword());
        EncryptedMessage pword = new EncryptedMessage(loginPword);

        uname.encrypt();
        clientOutputStream.writeObject(uname);
        pword.encrypt();
        clientOutputStream.writeObject(pword);

        /* create a new thread of YourChat_ClientThread, sending input  
           stream variable as a parameter */
        thread = new YourChat_ClientThread(clientInputStream);
        thread.run();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
} 

void closeStreams()
{   try
{   // close input stream 
    clientOutputStream.close();
    // close output stream 
    clientInputStream.close();
    // close socket 
    socket.close();
}
catch(IOException e) // thrown by method close
{   System.out.println(e);
System.exit(1); 
}
}

void addBroadcast(String s)
{   // add a message to the broadcast text output area
    broadcastArea.append(s + "\n");
    broadcastArea.setCaretPosition(broadcastArea.getText().length());
}

void getConnections() { try
{   // initialise a socket and get a connection to server
    socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 6000);
    // get input & output object streams
    clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    clientInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

}
catch(UnknownHostException e) // thrown by method getLocalHost
{   System.out.println(e);
System.exit(1); 
}
catch(IOException e) // thrown by methods ObjectOutputStream, ObjectInputStream
{   System.out.println(e);
System.exit(1); 
} 
}

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * ----------------------YourChat_ClientThread Class------------------------
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
public class YourChat_ClientThread{
    ObjectInputStream threadInputStream;

    public YourChat_ClientThread(ObjectInputStream in){
        threadInputStream = in;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            Boolean loggedOn = (Boolean)clientInputStream.readObject();
            participantNo = clientInputStream.readInt();

            if(loggedOn){
                CompressedMessage welcome = (CompressedMessage) clientInputStream.readObject();
                welcome.decompress();
                String message = welcome.getMessage();

                setUpChat(loggedOn);

                String inMessage;
                CompressedMessage cMessage;
                while(loggedOn){
                    cMessage = (CompressedMessage)clientInputStream.readObject();
                    cMessage.decompress();
                    inMessage = cMessage.getMessage();

                    //identfier is the first char of the message
                    char identifier = inMessage.charAt(0);
                    //once the char identifier has been taken, the char can be removed from the string
                    inMessage = inMessage.substring(1, inMessage.length());
                    if (identifier == 'q'){
                        addBroadcast(inMessage); 
                    } else if(identifier == 'g'){
                        addBroadcast(inMessage); 
                        closeStreams(); 
                        c.setEnabled(false);

                    } else if(identifier == 'j'){
                        addBroadcast(inMessage);
                        CompressedMessage usernameMessage = (CompressedMessage)clientInputStream.readObject();
                        usernameMessage.decompress();
                        String username = usernameMessage.getMessage();

                        switch (username){
                        case "Arken":   btnArken.setEnabled(true);      break;
                        case "Ben":     btnBen.setEnabled(true);        break;
                        case "Darklark":btnDarklark.setEnabled(true);   break;
                        case "Free":    btnFree.setEnabled(true);       break;
                        }

                    }else if(identifier == 'o'){

                    }

                }
            } else{
                CompressedMessage denied = (CompressedMessage) clientInputStream.readObject();
                denied.decompress();
                String message = denied.getMessage();
                closeStreams();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }catch(IOException e1){
            System.out.println(e1);
            System.exit(1);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e1){
            System.out.println(e1);
            System.exit(1);

        }
    }

    public void disableWindow(){
        btnBen.setEnabled(false);
        btnArken.setEnabled(false);
        btnDarklark.setEnabled(false);
        btnFree.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

//main method
public static void main(String [] args){
    YourChat_Client client = new YourChat_Client();
    client.getConnections();
}
```

}

Comment: Please remove unnecessary parts of code and focus on the part that causing the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See also [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.  I don;t know for sure that is the cause of the problem, but noted that the GUI makes some server calls (that might take a while to complete) yet declares no `SwingWorker` instances.

Answer (score 3):

Please read the Java tutorial lesson: ([Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)).

You are starting a thread `YourChat_ClientThread` that updates the GUI outside the EDT. This can cause several update and GUI problems. In Swing all GUI updates must be performed within the event dispatching thread (EDT).

I am not sure if that's your root problem but you should cleanup your code regarding the EDT before checking for other problems.